# Use A button column for the Gridview as a trigger for other GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a Grid-view (first Grid) with a button column (first Grid)
i want this button to be a trigger for the update-panel that contains another Gird-view (second Grid) without refreshing the whole page(without full post back that fired with button as a server side control) so the scenario will be as the following:

1. user will click the button for any row at (first Grid)
2. the  Second Grid will be only updated with related records without
   refresh the whole page

So how to achieve that ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the second gridview mark up with an `UpdatePanel` like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel id="up1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="firstGridviewId"/>
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%-- second gridview markup here --%>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: ok but when i press that button will not make postback for whole page because the control is a server side control?

Comment: i tried it and i get error "A control with ID 'btnExam' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel" which this button in the first gridview

Comment: Yes, it will make a postback, but it will be asynchronous and only 2nd gridview will be updated (not the whole page). I suspect you have put the _button id_ in the trigger markup (which wont work); you will have to put the _gridview id_ there